# Failed to Load Custom Cell from dequeue reusable UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using xib file to create a custom cell. The reuse identifier is set up in the xib file. Then I have a lazy var that I use to register the nib only once:

```
private lazy var registerNib: Bool = {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Custom")

    return true
}()
```

During Cell Creating I just used the lazy var and dequeue the cell from the table view, using the same reuse identifier that I have in the xib file:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let _ = self.registerNib
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Custom") as! CustomCell

    return cell
}
```

But the unwrapping fails and the app crashes.

> tableView.dequeueReusableCell returns nil

for some reason....

Comment: @Sh_Khan I don't think it's needed: the reason is that the dequeue method returns nil. That's enough as an information about the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods named `dequeueReusableCell`.

- [`dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell)
- [`dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecell)

*But the unwrapping fails and the app crashes. tableView.dequeueReusableCell returns nil **for some reason**....*

You are using the first one and the doc clearly says

> ### Return Value
>
> A `UITableViewCell` object with the associated `identifier` or `nil` if no such object exists in the reusable-cell queue.

---

You may want to use the latter.
Change the line:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Custom") as! CustomCell
```

To:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Custom", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your nib object in `viewDidLoad():` method like this

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)

tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Custom")
```

Also, did you set the cell reuse identifier in the storyboard?